# How to resample raster exportation with ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, export

I noticed the resolution of a programmatically exported raster was not as good as the same image exported with the ArcMap GUI. I set the resample ratio in the GUI to 3 and the quality seemed identical. I tried to do the same thing in code but it doesn't seem to be changing the quality at all:

```
private static IExport GetExporterObject()
{
    IExport newExporter = new ExportPDFClass();
    IOutputRasterSettings rasterSettings = (newExporter as IOutputRasterSettings);
    rasterSettings.ResampleRatio = 1;
    return (IExport)rasterSettings;
}

private static IEnvelope GetExporterRectangle(double ratio, IActiveView activeView, out tagRECT exporterRectangle)
{
    IEnvelope pixelBox = new EnvelopeClass();
    pixelBox.XMin = activeView.ExportFrame.left * ratio;
    pixelBox.XMax = activeView.ExportFrame.right * ratio;
    pixelBox.YMin = activeView.ExportFrame.top * ratio;
    pixelBox.YMax = activeView.ExportFrame.bottom * ratio;

    //I did the following code this way because I found that converting the ratio to int  
    //was rounding it down before multiplying and giving me the wrong dimensions
    exporterRectangle.left = (int)(activeView.ExportFrame.left * ratio);
    exporterRectangle.right = (int)(activeView.ExportFrame.right * ratio);
    exporterRectangle.top = (int)(activeView.ExportFrame.top * ratio);
    exporterRectangle.bottom = (int)(activeView.ExportFrame.bottom * ratio);

    return pixelBox;
}

public static void ExportMapPage(IMxDocument mxd, MapPage mapPage, string outputPath)
{
    mxd.ActiveView = mxd.PageLayout as IActiveView;
    IActiveView activeView = mxd.ActiveView;
    activeView.FocusMap.MapScale = mapPage.Scale;
    mxd.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewAll, null, activeView.Extent);
    string output = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}", outputPath, mapPage.Year, GetFileExtension(mapPage.FileFormat));

    IExport exporter = GetExporterObject();
    exporter.ExportFileName = output;
    exporter.Resolution = mapPage.DPI;

    tagRECT exporterRectangle;
    exporter.PixelBounds = GetExporterRectangle(mapPage.Ratio, activeView, out exporterRectangle);

    int hdc = exporter.StartExporting();
    activeView.Output(hdc, (int)exporter.Resolution, ref exporterRectangle, null, null);
    exporter.FinishExporting();
    exporter.Cleanup();
    mxd.UpdateContents();
}
```

I also noticed in the documentation there appears to be a discrepency.

This [link](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjectsonline/componenthelp/esriCore/IOutputRasterSettings.htm) says DisplayTransformation is the only coclass that implements IOutputRasterSettings, while this [link](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/ComponentHelp/esriDisplay/IOutputRasterSettings.htm) says many do. Does anyone know which is correct? I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 and SDK 10.1 but I'm not sure how that reflects the ArcObjects version I'm using.

EDIT: It appears that DisplayTransformation is the coclass to use. I found that casting IActiveView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation to IOutputRasterSettings told me that the ResampleRatio property was in fact set to 3 by default. However even when I added this code immediately before the exporter.StartExporting() line, the output still looks the same as the ratio being set to 3.

```
IDisplayTransformation dispTrans = activeView.ScreenDisplay.DisplayTransformation; 
(dispTrans as IOutputRasterSettings).ResampleRatio = 1;
```

In the [documentation](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriCarto/IActiveView_Output.htm) it specifically says at the bottom that changing this property will affect the results of the IActiveView.Output method, so I assume there is something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_set_output_image_quality/000100000021000000/), you need to loop through the map elements to find the IMapFrame and cast it to IActiveView::IOutputRasterSettings to access the ResampleRatio of the map element. Setting the ratio by having IActiveView set to PageLayout will not affect the resampling of the PageLayout output. With this I was able to get the output quality to look right.